# passing an Object to a method?

Tags: java, object, registration

**public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
}**

What does this line mean in detail, apart from that ActionEvent 's reference is being passed to actionPerformed method.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Your title seems to suggest it's about the one thing you've said it *isn't* about in the text (passing the reference).

Answer (score 8):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) { }
```

- `public`: Method is accessible from any code.
- `void`: Method doesn't return anything.
- `actionPerformed`: Name of method.
- `(`: You're beginning to specify the parameter list.
- `ActionEvent`: Type of parameter #1.
- `actionEvent`: Name of parameter #1.
- `)`: You've finished specifying the parameter list.
- `{ }`: Method doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 4):

This method is part of ActionListener interface.

```
public class Listener implements ActionListener{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Listener listener = new Listener();
    Button button = new Button();
    button.addActionListener(listener);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}
```

}

When the user will press the button, the method actionPerformed of Listener class will be invoked.